# Matching subquery in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called TABLE1 with 3 columns: month distinct_count, cobrand_id.

I would like to call the value in the distinct_count column for rows that match the month and cobrand_id columns.

Table1:

[image]

For example, I am using the following query on another table called Table2 that has some overlapping fields with Table1:

```
SELECT to_char(transaction_date, 'YYYY-MM') as month, 
cobrand_id, 
Amount, 
CASE WHEN month = Table1.month and cobrand_id = Table2.cobrand_id 
THEN #return matching distinct_count value from Table 1# as newval

FROM Table2
WHERE DESCRIPTION iLIKE '%Criteria%';
```

I need help calculating newval.

Logically, newval should return the value from the distinct_count column in TABLE1 that matches the month & cobrand_id values returned from the query above from TABLE2.

Edit: TABLE2 does not have a column called distinct_count.  I am looking to pull the value distinct_count for each row as newval in my query where month & cobrand_id match across TABLE1 and TABLE2.

Comment: Hint:  `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

According to you sql sentence because you mention only 3 columns, but you're using `'transaction_date'`, `'DESCRIPTION'` and `'Amount'`

```
 SELECT 
    to_char(Table2.transaction_date, 'YYYY-MM') as month, 
    Table2.cobrand_id, 
    Table2.Amount,
    Table1.distinct_count as newval
 FROM
     Table2
     inner join Table1
         on to_char(Table2.transaction_date, 'YYYY-MM') = Table1.month
         and Table2.cobrant_id = Table1.cobrant_id
WHERE
    Table2.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%Criteria%';
```

Comment: Hi McNets - Table1 has only 3 columns, but Table2 has 20+ columns including the 3 columns from Table1.  I'm trying to pull data from Table2, but each row includes distinct_count from Table 1 where Table 2(cobrand_id & month) = Table1(cobrand_id & month).

Comment: Then Amount and Description are fields of Table1?

Comment: Amount and Description are not in Table1.  Just Month, Distinct_count and cobrand_ID as shown above.  There is no Distinct_count in Table2.  I'm trying to run a query against Table2 and pull Distinct_count as Newval from Table1 where Cobrand_ID and Month match.

Comment: Thanks mcNets.  One last question.  Is there any way to avoid writing Table2 before all the fields in the top Select clause.  Aren't we pulling "FROM Table2," so why is it necessary to specify TABLE2.  Thank you.

Comment: No, you can select only the fields you need, but you must use the inner join clause to link table1 and table2

Comment: But if I remove Table2 from the top select clauses, I get [42702] ERROR: column reference "cobrand_id" is ambiguous.

Comment: if the same field exists in both tables, you must use this form: table.field just to inform sql witch field are you retrieving.